# Django class based views success_url

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to set the success_url on a django class based UpdateView but cannot get it to work. I have tried the syntax suggested in the docs

```
success_url="/polls/%(slug)s/"
```

But it is not working. How can I access the model fields in the success_url?

Comment: This relies on the object field attributes. In the example you've posted, the model should have a `slug` field. Posting the view's class code would help as well.

Comment: OK, I seem to be able to access the model fields. any idea how I can access fields on related models?

Comment: See the answer below, which takes into account the info you've provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This relies on object field attributes. In the example you've posted, the model should have a slug field.

For related fields:

You can try using django's __ notation for related objects (e.g: `user__username`) in `success_url`, not sure if it'll work.

IMO in such cases a better practice is overriding `get_success_url()`, and returning the url taking into account `self.object`.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I actually was able to not set the success_url at all and allow it to automatically use the the objects get_absolute_url() method.

Comment: Yep, that's the fallback option ;-)